# How to go from .SD syntax to for set syntax with data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, set

From the *foo.in* data.table, and thanks to the help that I was able to receive here, I manage to get what I wanted : *foo.out*.

```
set.seed(123)
foo.in <- data.table(id = rep(LETTERS[1:10], each = 10),
                  code = sample(c(111, 222, 333, 444), 100, replace = TRUE),
                  cof = rep(runif(10, 1, 10), each = 10),
                  x1 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                  x2 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                  x3 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                  x4 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                  x5 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                  x6 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE))

foo.out <- foo.in[, lapply(.SD, function(x) uniqueN(code[x==1]) * cof), 
                    .SDcols = grep("^x\\d+$", names(foo.in)), 
                     by = .(id, cof)]
```

It works fine, but with a very large data.table I would like to test another syntax with `for` and `set`.

By documenting myself, I understood that depending on the case, it could be faster than using `.SD`.
Even if it turns out not, it's a good exercice to learn and run my own benchmarks.

But I can't do it with this syntax...

My attempt :

```
cols <- paste0("x", c(1:6))
for (c in cols) { set(foo.in, j = c, value = ...) }
```

Thanks !!

Comment: `foo.in` is 100 rows. `foo.out` is 10 rows. You are aggregating and summarizing the data. While `set()` can be good for some use cases, this example is not a great use case because of the aggregation.

Comment: @Cole Oh ok, thanks, I thought it was the other way around. Thank you for the info. But maybe you could help me find the right syntax with ```set()``` ? I still can't do it.

Comment: I cannot think of a logical way to aggregate while using set.  Please see `?set`, but the main use case for `set` is when you have to call `[.data.table` many times and you want less overhead. In the original example, you are only calling `[.data.table` once.  Lastly, see your ` value = ...`. This is hard! and it is hard because we need to aggregate. And one way to aggregate efficiently is to directly aggregate within a `[.data.table` call.